# Can docpad-plugin-ghpages be hosted on GitHub Pages?

Tags: plugins, github-pages, docpad

I am Thinking of moving my Jekyll site to Docpad and was reading through documentation but was unclear on whether I could use docpad-plugin-ghpages with project pages for organistions where GitHub pages hosts at **orgname**.github.io/**projectname**

For example my current website (on GitHub at https://github.com/jesusdiedforme/jesusdiedfor.me) is hosted at *jesusdiedforme.github.io/jesusdiedfor.me* (then CNAMEd to my domain)

Any help would be appreciated thanks

ian

Answer (score 0):

Yes! You can use `docpad-plugin-ghpages` to generate a site for GitHub Organization pages as well.  There is nothing specific to personal pages, just substitute `https://github.com/username/username.github.io.git` for `https://github.com/organization/organization.github.io.git`.